# Insert data from excel file in MySql database using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans-7

I want to insert data from excel file in MySql database table using JSP, found the following link for using Apache PO library for OFFICE applications.

Using NetBeans IDE and added all the libraries given under that link:

http://java2carrer.blogspot.in/2012/10/insert-data-into-database-from-excel.html

I tried it, connections and all. Student Table consists of 3 fields:
But getting this error:

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page
    /readExcel2.jsp at line 72

    69: //printCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);
    70: con=connection.getConn();
    71: String query="insert into Student values(?,?,?)";
    72: ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
    73: int count=0;
    74: ArrayList cellStoreArrayList=null;
    75: //For inserting into database


    Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.ja  va:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    root cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.readExcel2_jsp._jspService(readExcel2_jsp.java:154)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I'm also confused abou the fact that I started with new "Web Application" project under NetBeansIDE and readExcel.jsp code and then inserted java class file and added DB_COnnection.java code there.
It is shown here that DB_Connection.java is under DB package(folder).
So I've done the same. So java file link is now :

```
    "C:\Users\aman\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\src\java\DB\DB_Connection.java"
```

I'm going toward right direction?
What this error about?

Comment: try enclosing the code in a try/catch block and give us the stacktrace

Comment: stacktrace is visible, you can see..it's already under try-catch...

Comment: Are you sure your `con` is not `null` as the NPE says?

Comment: Yes, it is not null...I've checked

Comment: I've now connected this without using beans and now it is not showing error..

Answer (score 0):

I tried the link what you have given and its working fine. Please try again. And you are saying your java file link is src/java/DB/DB_Connection but in the link its in src/DB/DB_Connection. If you are using this path then in jsp page

```
<jsp:useBean id="connection" class="java.DB.DB_Connection" scope="page">
    <jsp:setProperty name="connection" property="*"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```